# How to make multiple jQuery animations run at the same time?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

As it stands there us a difference between the two and I want them to run at the same time. Here is the code:

```
$(selector1).animate({
    height: '670'
}, 2000, function() {
    // Animation complete.  
});

$(selector2).animate({
    top: '670'
}, 2000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
});​
```

Comment: the first one overlaps the second one

Comment: nested animation ...  the one into the other

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using `queue:false`. You can see the full [docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)here.

```
$(selector1).animate({
    height: '670'
}, {
    duration: 2000,
    queue: false,
    complete: function() { /* Animation complete */ }
});

$(selector2).animate({
    top: '670'
}, {
    duration: 2000,
    queue: false,
    complete: function() { /* Animation complete */ }
});
```

### Docs:

> **.animate( properties, options )**    version added: 1.0
>
> ---
>
> **properties** A map of CSS properties that the animation will move toward.
>   **options** A map of additional options to pass to the method. Supported keys:
>   `duration:` A string or number determining how long the animation will run.
>   `easing:` A string indicating which easing function to use for the transition.
>   `complete:` A function to call once the animation is complete.
>   `step:` A function to be called after each step of the animation.
>   **`queue:`** A Boolean indicating whether to place the animation in the effects queue. If false, the animation will begin immediately. As of jQuery 1.7, the queue option can also accept a string, in which case the animation is added to the queue represented by that string.
>   `specialEasing:` A map of one or more of the CSS properties defined by the properties argument and their corresponding easing functions (added 1.4).

Comment: It might be simple/clear _to you_, but everyone has different areas of expertise. Copying large chunks of the documentation (most of which is irrelevant to this answer) is not that useful since you still haven't really explained what `queue` does. There is nothing to indicate that the OP has not already read the documentation and still wanted to ask a question.

Comment: @andyb Andy I see what you say. I think the question ask for at solution on how to prevent an animation to be chained/queue and the docs intro section says: `if false, the animation will begin immediately.` I can see how this can be anymore clear.

Comment: I just meant that the other options in the documentation block in your answer are not relevant to this answer, for example the `easing` and `step` options are not relevant. I also commented that the tone of your opening sentence seemed a bit harsh - the answer might be clear _to you_ but maybe not to everyone else, especially the OP

Comment: @andyb You are right that my opening sentence can seem a bit harsh. But with clear I mean: So strait forward question, so elegant simple & understandable question may (or may not) could be found on the docs page.

Answer (score 3):

use queue variable as false...

```
$(function () {
    $("selector1").animate({
     height: '200px'
   }, { duration: 2000, queue: false });
    $("selector2").animate({
     height: '600px'
   }, { duration: 2000, queue: false });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

While it's true that consecutive calls to animate will give the appearance they are running at the same time, the underlying truth is they're distinct animations running very close to parallel.

To insure the animations are indeed running at the same time use:

```
$(function() {
    $('selector1').animate({..., queue: 'selector-animation'});
    $('selector2').animate({..., queue: 'selector-animation'}).dequeue('selector-animation');
});
```

Further animations can be added to the 'selector-animation' queue and all can be initiated provided the last animation dequeue's them.

Cheers,
Anthony

Answer (score 0):

You can create a selector expression that will select both elments, see here for a working example: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EF4wJ/2/).

HTML

```
<div id="blah">Blah</div>
<div id="bleh">Bleh</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="animate" />
​
```

Javascript

```
function anim() {
    $('#blah, #bleh').animate({
        height: '670'
    }, 2000, function() {
        // Animation complete.  
    });
}
$(function(){
    $('#btn').on('click', anim);
});​
```